# Discord.js Music Bot in a command handler

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I want to make a music bot in my command handler, but I ran into some problems.
This is the command handler I use:

```
delete require.cache[require.resolve(`./commands/${command}.js`)];
    
let commandFile = require(`./commands/${command}.js`);
commandFile.run(client, message, args);
```

And in my play.js file I have a queue:

```
var servers = {};
```

I don't know how to make it so that I can skip a song (using the skip command - skip.js) in the queue. Code for skipping:

```
if (server.dispatcher) server.dispatcher.end();
```

I tried looking at tutorials but they all do it in one file which makes it easier because you can just put the "var servers = {};" on the top and its going to work. I couldn't find any tutorials where they shown how to make it so that you can use a command handler like mine.

Here are all the files:

play.js - https://hastebin.com/dijavugufu.js

skip.js - https://hastebin.com/kupecayotu.js

It would also be nice if someone told me how to modify some other music bot commands to work with a command handler.

Answer (score 1):

Hey man not sure if you're still looking for an answer but I'm also working on a bot with a command handler. The way I got around this was to export the skip function directly from the play file and use that function in the skip file. Here's kinda what I did.

```
/*In play.js*/
var dispatcher;
async function Play(connection, message){
    dispatcher = await connection.playStream("your url and options here");
}
module.exports.Skip = function(){
    if(dispatcher) dispatcher.end();
}

/*In skip.js*/
const playModule = require("your_path_to/play.js");
module.exports.run = async (client, message, args) => {
    var skip = playModule.Skip();
}
```

Sorry, I'm still pretty new to Node.js and creating a Discord bot and this may not be the most elegant solution. But the main point is that I got around it by writing the function in play.js and exporting that function to skip.js and calling it there.