# My Discord.js bot uses a command handler. How can I then create play/skip/pause/resume/etc commands in different files?

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I set up the command handler for my bot using the [Discord.js guide](https://discordjs.guide/command-handling/#dynamically-reading-command-files) (I am relatively new to Discord.js, as well as JavaScript itself, I'd say). However, as all my commands are in different files, is there a way that I can share variables between the files? I've tried experimenting with exporting modules, but sadly could not get it to work.

For example (I think it's somewhat understandable, but still), to skip a song you must first check if there is actually any audio streaming (which is all done in the play file), then end the current stream and move on to the next one in the queue (the variable for which is also in the play file).

I have gotten a separate music bot up and running, but all the code is in one file, linked together by if/else if/else chains. Perhaps I could just copy this code into the main file for my other bot instead of using the command handler for those specific commands?

I assume that there is a way to do this that is quite obvious, and I apologize if I am wasting peoples' time.

Also, I don't believe code is required for this question but if I'm wrong, please let me know.

Thank you in advance.

EDIT: 
I have also read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53091718/discord-js-music-bot-in-a-command-handler?rq=1) multiple times beforehand and have tried the solution, although I haven't gotten it to work.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to "carry over" variables without exporting anything is to assign them to a property of your client. That way, wherever you have your `client` (or `bot`) variable, you also have access to the needed information without requiring a file.

For example...

`ready.js` (assuming you have an event handler; otherwise your `ready` event)

```js
client.queue = {};
for (guild of client.guilds) client.queue[guild.id] = [];
```

`play.js`

```js
const queue = client.queue[message.guild.id];
queue.push({ song: 'Old Town Road', requester: message.author.id });
```

`queue.js`

```js
const queue = client.queue[message.guild.id];

message.channel.send(`**${queue.length}** song${queue.length !== 1 ? 's' : ''} queued.`)
  .catch(console.error);
```